# TypeORM - Retrieve data through relation query in resolver

Tags: graphql, apollo, typeorm

So I'm trying to retrieve elements out of a join relation in an Apollo resolver.

I've got a User table, a Notification table. And a Relation table named:

`notification_recipients_user` defined by a ManyToMany relation on both entity but hosted on Notification :

```
//entity/Notification.ts
  @ManyToMany(type => User, recipient => recipient.notifications)
  @JoinTable()
  recipients: User[];
```

I can create relation without problem through this mutation :

```
    addNotificationForUser: async (_, { id, data }) => {
      const user = await User.findOne({ id });
      if (user) {
        const notification = await Notification.create({
          template: data,
          recipients: [user]
        }).save()
        return notification;
      } else {
        throw new Error("User does not exists!");
      }
    }
```

However I'm totally not succeeding in retrieving data for a specific User.

```
    allNotificationsOfUser: (_, { user }, ___) => {
      return Notification.find({
        where: { userId: user },
        relations: ['recipients'],
      })
```

[image]

The method find is one of [TypeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/repository-api.md) native methods.

However I must be doing something wrong because it react as if there wasn't any filter.

Comment: Did you just insert multiple notifications? Not sure your problem is on the read part. The create part will instanciate a new object (not fetched from an old value from database) so chances are you insert a new item everytime, getting multiples in database. Use a raw select SQL query to check that.

Comment: @zenbeni answered it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the best way of doing it is by using relation between entity.

So to get Notification you'll go by User.notifications

```
allUnseenNotificationsOfUser: async (_, { userId }, __) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    relations: ["notifications"],
    where: { id: userId }
  });
  if (user) {
    const notifications = user.notifications.filter(notification => !notification.seen)
    return notifications;
  }
  return null;
}
```

And for the record for anyone stumbeling upon this you can use filter on your result to do a query like resolver.

`const notifications = user.notifications.filter(notification => !notification.seen)`

It feels tricky but works like a charm.